# SQL запрос обновления. Смещение данных на строку выше

Tags: sql, postgresql, update

Подскажите как выполнить подобный запрос на обновление:

Необходимо сместить все записи по определенным ID в одном из столбцов CreatedAt на одну позицию выше, что бы лучше продемонстрировать сказанное прилагаю изображения, до обновления с обозначениями что именно надо сделать и после:

До обновления(как именно надо обновлять):

[image: До обновления как именно надо производить обновление]

После обновления:

[image: После обновления]

P.S. База postgresql

Comment: Лишние теги удалены.

Comment: *До обновления*... *После обновления*... а набор записей-то не изменился! То есть вообще никак. Просто `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC NULLS LAST` - и ничего обновлять не нужно.

Comment: А записи в каком порядке ? как вы понимаете какая строка в группе первая ? а так делаете сначала select с `lead(CreatedAt) over(partition by id order by Data)` (вот order by вам надо на подходящий заменить), он вам даст выборку со смещением. А потом на основе него делаете update

Comment: @Mike спасибо, записи надо сортировать по createdAt от меньших к большим а не как у меня. Первая строка в группе в ней будет null. Можете написать свой вариант в полноценном ответе?